# Matching size columns in 2 dataframes based on location and size range when the ID matches. Complex data wrangling R

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr, matching

I have 2 dataframes. auto and manual. I need to create matching instances between 2 data frames when auto_size and manual_size falls within +/- 25 range within each and when the loactions are matched, while the ID is matching. Location matching:
right to right and middle,
middle to right,middle and left
left to left and middle

- the actual datsets are more bigger than this containing thousands of records.

```
auto <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                           "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6", 
                           "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
                           "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
                           "7", "7"), 
                    auto_repeat_tag = c(8, 1, 3, 7, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 1, 2, 
                                        1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
                                        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,25, 26), 
                    auto_size = c(11, 10, 8, 8, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 20,17, 8, 6, 4, 3, 13, 11, 8,
                                  8, 5, 2, 11, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8,7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5,
                                  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3),
                    auto_location = c("left", "middle", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left",
                                      "left", "left","middle", "left", "left", "left", "left","left", "left", "left","left", "left", "left", "left", "middle", "left", "middle", "middle", 
                                      "left", "middle", "left", "left", "middle", "left", "middle", 
                                      "middle", "middle", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left","left", "left", "middle", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left","left"))



manual <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "7"), 
                    manual_repeat_tag = c(2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
                    manual_size = c(6, 6, 4, 4,4, 3, 3, 25, 17, 3, 10, 3, 3, 2),
                    manual_location = c("left","middle", "left", "left", "left", "middle", "left", "left", "left", 
                                        "left", "left", "left", "left", "left"))
```

Upto now first I merged 2 files so that I can create all the possible instances between 2 dataframes. Then created seperate columns for +/- 25% columns for each size.

```
auto_manual<-merge(auto,manual,by="ID")

auto_manual<- auto_manual%>%
  mutate(auto_plus50size=auto_size+(auto_size/4),
         auto_minus50size=auto_size-(auto_size/4),
         manual_plus50size=manual_size+(manual_size/4),
         manual_minus50size=manual_size-(manual_size/4))
```

Then I created a match size and match location column depending on the criteria.

```
## Matching auto and manual SIZE (matching auto range with manual size range and vice versa)
auto_manual%<>%
  mutate(match_size= case_when(manual_minus50size>=auto_minus50size& 
                                 manual_minus50size<=auto_plus50size~paste0("auto",auto_size,"man",manual_size),
                               manual_plus50size>=auto_minus50size& 
                                 manual_plus50size<=auto_plus50size~paste0("auto",auto_size,"man",manual_size),
                               auto_minus50size>=manual_minus50size&
                                 auto_minus50size<=manual_plus50size~paste0("auto",auto_size,"man",manual_size),
                               auto_plus50size>=manual_minus50size&
                                 auto_plus50size<=manual_plus50size~paste0("auto",auto_size,"man",manual_size),
                               TRUE~"not_matching")) %>% 
  relocate(match_size,.after = ID)


## Matching auto and manual location
#left can be matched to left and middle
#middle to right,left,middle
#right to right and middle

auto_manual%<>%
  mutate(match_location=case_when(auto_location =="right"& 
                                    (manual_location %in% c("right","middle"))~"matched",
                                  auto_location=="middle" &
                                    ( manual_location %in% c("right","middle","left"))~"matched",
                                  auto_location =="left" &
                                    ( manual_location %in% c("middle","left"))~"matched",
                                  manual_location=="right" & 
                                    (auto_location %in% c("right","middle"))~"matched",
                                 manual_location=="middle" & 
                                    (auto_location %in% c("right","middle","left"))~"matched",
                                  manual_location=="left" & 
                                    (auto_location %in% c("middle","left"))~"matched",
                                  TRUE~"not_matching")) %>% 
  relocate(match_location,.after = match_size)
```

Finally I extracted all the instances both location and sizes are matching.

```
#### Both size and location matched
matched<-auto_manual %>% 
  filter(match_size!="not_matching" & match_location!="not_matching") %>% 
  select(ID,match_size,match_location,auto_repeat_tag,manual_repeat_tag,auto_size,manual_size)

matched <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                            "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", 
                            "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7"),
                     match_size = c("auto10man6", "auto10man6", "auto8man6", "auto8man6",  "auto8man6", "auto8man6","auto7man6", "auto7man6", "auto6man6", "auto6man6", "auto6man4", 
"auto6man4", "auto6man4", "auto4man6", "auto4man6", "auto4man4", 
"auto4man4", "auto4man4", "auto4man6", "auto4man6", "auto4man4", 
"auto4man4", "auto4man4", "auto4man3", "auto4man3", "auto4man3", 
"auto4man3", "auto3man3", "auto8man10", "auto5man3", "auto2man3", 
"auto5man3", "auto5man3", "auto5man3", "auto5man3", "auto5man3", 
"auto5man3", "auto5man3", "auto3man3", "auto3man2", "auto3man3","auto3man2"), 
                     match_location = c("matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched","matched", "matched",  "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched",
"matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", 
 "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", 
"matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", 
"matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched", "matched","matched", "matched", "matched"), 
                     auto_repeat_tag = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3,1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25, 26,26), 
                     manual_repeat_tag = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2), 
                     auto_size = c(10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 8, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                     manual_size = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2))
```

As all the above in the matched dataframe are matching instances I want to extract best matches according to the criterion that one repeat instance only matched once and the highest size from auto or manual should match first.
Can someone help me writing a piece of function or way to do this using dplyr.

Thank you in advance

**** update
The final dataframe should look something like this

```
    best_fit1<- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7), 
                      match_size = c("auto10man6", "auto8man6", "auto4man3",                                          "auto3man3","auto8man10",                                                        "auto5man3","auto5man3", "auto3man2"), 
                      match_location = c("matched", "matched", "matched",                                               "matched","matched", "matched",                                                  "matched", "matched"), 
                      auto_repeat_tag = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 18, 25),
                      manual_repeat_tag = c(1,  2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
                      auto_size = c(10, 8, 4, 3, 8, 5, 5, 3), 
                      manual_size = c(6, 6, 3, 3, 10, 3, 3, 2))
```

Comment: "according to the criterion that one repeat instance only matched once" can you tell me which column should have no duplicates of? I assume ID but maybe it's multiple columns

Comment: also, at points you say +/- 25, and then at others it's +/- 25%

Comment: Hi Mark, Each repeat instance is unique within each Id. So when matching one repeat instance within the ID should only be matched once.  Sorry for the typo, it should be +/-25%.

Comment: repeat instance of what? It would be helpful if you could break down what you would like to group by at the end. Explain it like I'm 5

Comment: Hi Mark, I have updated the question with the final dataframe (best_fit). Repeat_tag is created whenever a new size is recorded. If a particular ID has only one size recorded, it has 1 under repeat_tag. If an ID has two sizes recorded in the size column it has 1 and 2 in the repeat_tag column. This repeat_tag column is created because sometimes the sizes recorded can be same (eg: if one ID has 2 and 2 in the size column, but different numbers in repeat_tag column, even if the size is same, that should be considered as 2 sizes, because the repeat_tag corresponding to those sizes are different).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you're looking for:

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(auto, manual, by = "ID", relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
    filter(!(auto_location == "left" & manual_location == "right") & 
                !(auto_location == "right" & manual_location == "left"),
                between(auto_size, manual_size - 25, manual_size + 25)) %>%
                mutate(m = max(auto_size, manual_size)) %>%
                slice_max(m, with_ties = FALSE, by = ID)

  ID auto_repeat_tag auto_size auto_location manual_repeat_tag manual_size
1  1               8        11          left                 2           6
2  2               3         4          left                 1           3
3  3               1         3          left                 1           3
4  4               1        13          left                 1           3
5  5               1         8          left                 1          10
6  6               3         8          left                 1           3
7  7               1        11        middle                 1           3
  manual_location  m
1            left 25
2          middle 25
3            left 25
4            left 25
5            left 25
6            left 25
7            left 25
```

Of the possible combinations of locations, only two (left right and right left) are bad, so we can just filter those ones out.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for this. But some IDs should have more than one matches. In other words, If matching criteria is fulfilled both ID and the repeat instance together should be unique. So, even if the size is similar if the repeat instance is different that should be taken as two sizes. Hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: what do you mean by "repeat instance"? Can you give an example/explain like I'm 5?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a fuzzy join. You can condense like 90% of your code into one function. You'll have to figure out the last step because I'm not following the logic of the best match:

```r
library(tidyverse)
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_full_join(auto, manual, 
                           by = c("ID", 
                                  "auto_size" = "manual_size", 
                                  "auto_location" = "manual_location"), 
                           match_fun = c(`==`,
                                         \(x, y) between(y, x - 0.25*x, x + 0.25*x),
                                         \(x, y) case_when(
                                           x == y  ~ TRUE,
                                           (x == "middle" | y == "middle") ~ TRUE,
                                           .default = FALSE
                                         )))
#> # A tibble: 62 x 8
#>    ID.x  auto_repeat_tag auto_size auto_location ID.y  manual_repeat_tag
#>    <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>         <chr>             <dbl>
#>  1 1                   3         8 left          1                     2
#>  2 1                   3         8 left          1                     1
#>  3 1                   7         8 left          1                     2
#>  4 1                   7         8 left          1                     1
#>  5 1                   5         7 left          1                     2
#>  6 1                   5         7 left          1                     1
#>  7 1                   4         6 left          1                     2
#>  8 1                   4         6 left          1                     1
#>  9 1                   6         4 left          1                     5
#> 10 1                   6         4 left          1                     4
#> # i 52 more rows
#> # i 2 more variables: manual_size <dbl>, manual_location <chr>
```

Comment: Hi AndS., thank you for this. Yeah I can shorten my code by using this. But still I am unable to find a way around to find the best fit via a code.After this step I need to go through all the sizes in manual and auto and extract what is the best match. To find it a size within an ID should only matched once. Sometimes size can be same like 2 and 2 but the repeat_tag can be different. In such occasions even if the size is same 2 matching instances can be created depending on the repeat_tag. What I think is I need to write a function when a match is created that record should be removed.